# Loading/updating UI after SMS.isAvailableAsync() resolved

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, expo

I'm having a lot of struggles with implementing `expo-sms` because it's async..

I would have liked to keep the splash screen on until I have gotten the answer (if SMS is possible) and then drop it into my `Context.js` (`React.createContext()`). But I had to give up and instead try to update the UI once I got the reply.

This is my attempt

```
// PureComponent
...
  state = {
    dishToOrder: null,
  }
...
async componentDidMount() {
    const smsCapable = await SMS.isAvailableAsync()
    this.setState({ smsCapable }, () => console.log('SMS: ', smsCapable))
  }

  ...

  render() {
    ...
    return (
      <ContextConsumer>
        {({ dishes, cart, addToCart, smsCart, clearCart }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              ...
              <FlatList
                data={dishes}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                  <Dish
                    ...
                    smsCapable={this.state.smsCapable}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

inside the `render()` of `Dish` (before the `return`) I do a `console.log(this.props.smsCapable)` and it logs some `undefined` (as expeced). But it does not seem to re-render even though that the `prop` `smsCapable` should be updated since the `state` is updated.

Why is it not updating as I expected?

Comment: Can't you find the value when you just console.log instead of 'this.setState'?

Comment: @hongdevelop I don't understand your question, sorry.